# Show that GL(n,R) is isomorphic to GL($R^n$)

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, group-isomorphism

I read in my book that the said isomorphism holds, but I am confused as to what exactly GL(**R<sup>n</sup>**) is.
Can someone help clarify this and how to show the above isomorphism.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ . I presume the book is using $\text{GL}(V)$ as notation for the group of vector space automorphisms of $V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a field $\mathbb F$, the group $GL(n,\mathbb F)$ is defined to be the invertible $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb F$, with matrix multiplication as the group operation.

For a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb F$, the group $GL(V;\mathbb F)$ is defined to be the group of $\mathbb F$-linear transformations from $V$ to itself, with function composition as the group operation. Taking $V$ to be the vector space $\mathbb F^n$ (i.e., the vector space whose elements are column vectors of size $n$ with entries in $\mathbb F$ and the obvious definitions of addition and scalar multiplication), we see that the isomorphism between $GL(n,\mathbb F)$ and $GL(\mathbb F^n;\mathbb F)$ is given by taking a linear transformation and writing it as a matrix in the standard basis of column vectors, namely
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix},\ldots,\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Thus $GL(n,\mathbb F)$ and $GL(\mathbb F^n;\mathbb F)$ are isomorphic. Specializing to the case $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$ answers your question.

Comment: The group of automorphisms of the ring $F^n$ is not $\text{GL}(n,F)$. Rather it is the semidirect product of $S_n$ and $\text{Aut}(F)^n$.

Comment: Good point, I was careless. Rephrasing in terms of vector space automorphisms.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen incorporated your comment in the answer by specifying the base field in the notation.