# How does go from $GL(V)$ to $GL_n(F)$? What is the relationship between these groups?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, automorphism-group, general-linear-group

How to go from $GL(V)$ to $GL_n(F)$?

During my exams, I was asked what is the difference between $GL(V)$, $GL_n(F)$, $GL_n(R)$, $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ etc. and how could one go for example from $GL(V)$ to $GL_n(F)$ and opposite. (It was probably meant as how does one obtain one type of general linear group from the other.)

I think the groups are defined like this:

- $GL(V)= \{ f: V \rightarrow V | \text{f is bijective and linear} \}$ = abstract automorphism group, not necessarilly with elements = matrices.
- $GL_n(F)$ = $n \times n$ invertible matrices with elements in a field $F$ (or a ring $R$ or real numbers in the other cases).

However, I am not sure for example how does one transform $GL(V)$ so it becomes $GL_n(F)$. Are there any extra conditions to put on $GL(V)$, e.g. somehow turning the $f$ elements from $GL(V)$into matrices? Or am I missing the point completely?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If $V$ has finite dimension $n$, then $GL(V)$ is isomorphic to $GL_n(F)$ (not sure if this is what you ask, though).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that GL(n,R) is isomorphic to GL($R^n$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248222/show-that-gln-r-is-isomorphic-to-glrn). It has a very detailed proof.

Comment: This is all about bases.

Comment: Second bullet: $GL_n(F)$ is usually not for an arbitrary ring $F$, but rather for a commutative ring with unit.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, the linked question certainly helps, but however, I am still interested what does Randall´s "This is all about bases" mean and how can the $GL(V)$ behave for a general $V$, not just $V = F^n$. Does the connection between $GL(V)$ and $GL_n(F)$ exist, because automorphisms on an (arbitrary) vector space $V$ can be written in matrix form? I am maybe asking more generally and more intuitively than the linked question does.

Comment: Every finite-dimensional $F$-vector space $V$ is isomorphic to $F^n$, so it is just about $V=F^n$, I think.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova   Every linear map $T: V \to V$ may be written as a matrix once an ordered basis for $V$ is chosen.  This gives an explicit iso between $GL(V)$ and $GL_n(F)$ assuming $V$ is $n$-dim.